# Stop PyCharm From Auto-Inserting Selected Text to Search Box

Tags: pycharm, macros, keyboard-shortcuts

When using a hotkey to perform a search, PyCharm will automatically paste selected text into the search box.

How can I stop this behavior so that when I open the search box with a selection made, it isn't auto pasted into the search box?

As an example, this is a snapshot where I had source code highlighted and opened the search box. You can see that the selected text was automatically inserted into the search bar.

[image: undesired behavior]

Comment: Selected text is automatically pasted, clipboard is not used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering how PyCharm works the easiest way to do this is [recording a macro](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-macros-in-the-editor.html#record-a-macro) and rebinding the `Find` <kbd>Ctrl + F</kbd> keyboard shortcut.

If you press <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + A</kbd> or go to `File` `>` `Settings` `>` `Keymap` and carefully examine all the [`Find` actions](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/guide/tips/find-action/) they all have the functionality of pasting the selected text into the search box. That can't be changed. So the alternative is recording a marco that combines the <kbd>Ctrl + F</kbd> action with a <kbd>backspace</kbd> to clear the search box.

[image: screenshot of find actions dialogue]

It's an easy 2 step process, go to `Edit` `>` `Macros` `>` `Start Macro Recording` having some text selected,  press the <kbd>Ctrl + F</kbd> and <kbd>backspace</kbd> and again go to `Edit` `>` `Macros` `>` `Stop Macro Recording`. Save the marco and give it a name.

Next rebind the <kbd>Ctrl + F</kbd> [keyboard shortcut to your macro](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-macros-in-the-editor.html#bind) by going to `File` `>` `Settings` `>` `Keymap` `>` `Macros`.

[image: screenshot keymap dialogue]

This gives the find functionality exactly as requested in the question.