# Paste a formatted and higlighted multiline text (SQL) into string literal in PyCharm

Tags: python, sql, string, pycharm, multiline

Is there a way in PyCharm to paste multiline text (SQL) into string literal? E.g.:

```sql
SELECT column1
     , column2
FROM table1
WHERE column3 IN
(
    SELECT TOP(1) column4
    FROM table2
    INNER JOIN table3
    ON table2.column1 = table3.column1
)
```

Into:

```py
sql = (
    "SELECT column1"
    "     , column2"
    "FROM table1"
    "..."
)
```

And ideally tell PyCharm it is text in SQL language to highlight syntax?

Comment: Hi Miro, I haven't mentioned this in my answer but: You can bind the template+copy-paste actions together into 1 single keyboard shortcut by creating a macro [see an example here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50475808). I didn't include that last step when I first wrote the answer because it wasn't clear in the question requirements if you also wanted that functionality. (Let me know, in any case it doesn't get much better than 1 single-key stroke. Having PyCharm auto-detect + auto-correct from a copy-paste isn't currently implemented and would require implementation.)

Comment: It might be possible (with some effort) to implement a specific [intention](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/intentions-settings.html). But I don't see that as being an overall practical solution because it would always incur in more work and clicks than the macro+template+shortcut solution. (I also think that should be a separate question.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way in PyCharm to paste multiline text (SQL) into string literal?

Yes. First you'll have to ["Create a  live template"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-editing-live-templates.html) and since you want to paste the right function to use would be [`clipboard()`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/template-variables.html#predefined_functions). You can do this by going to `File` `>` `Settings` `>` `Editor` `>` `Live Templates` as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

> And ideally tell PyCharm it is text in SQL language to highlight syntax?

Yes. You can do this by using ["language injection"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-language-injections.html) in the code segment. If you have it preconfiguered like shown in the following screenshot PyCharm should autodetect SQL and apply the syntax highlight. It can be set at `File` `>` `Settings` `>` `Editor` `>` `Intention`.

[image]

If you don't have the intention set to autodetect you can also do it manually by right-clicking and choosing "Show Context Actions" or pressing the light-bulb in  the code (this is made easier by putting the SQL code inside a string).

[image]

After choosing the SQL dialect you prefer, you can also fine-tune syntax highlight and syntax checks of the injected language.

| Functionalities | IDE path to dialogue |
| --- | --- |
| Syntax checks | `Settings` `>` `Editor` `>` `Inspections` `>` `SQL` |
| Syntax highlights | `Settings` `>` `Editor` `>` `Color Sheme` `>` `SQL` |

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I have added "highlighted" into the question title as ultimately that is also what I meant by writing "formatted". Simply copy/paste and see in PyCharm kind of the same thing as in SQL client.

Comment: I am completely missing SQL in "Settings > Editor > Inspections" and "Settings > Editor > Color Sheme > SQL", so I do not get that option in "Inject language or reference" at all. Is it only pro feature, not available in community edition? Can I add it somehow?

Comment: Ok, it is part of PyCharm professional version only, as part of Database Tools and SQL plugin.

Comment: @Miro ouch. There are plenty of [SQL plugins specifically for community-edition](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/search?products=pycharm_ce&search=sql) that probably add this functionality. I honestly don't know which to recommend, but at least my answer addressed the issue for vanilla Pro-version and shows the general direction to go in. I think you're likely to find a plugin exactly for this since SQL is so prevalent.

Comment: @Miro does community-edition have the first link to `intentions` and `language injections`? [The documentation doesn't say](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-language-injections.html) if it's exclusive to Pro. Even without fine tuned checks&highlights if you have the "language injection" and "intentions" you should be able to get some kind of SQL default.

Comment: Yes, community version has "Inject language or reference" as shown in your picture, just no SQL options in it. Which I believe are being fed from "Settings > Editor > Inspections" where there is no SQL inspection item. But there is an option to duplicate / import / export profile so surely it can be added to the profile or profile with SQL inspection can be imported. Just can't find any open source one.

Answer (score 3):

For multiline SQL queries, in Python, you can use triple-quote:

```py
query = """
SELECT column1
     , column2
FROM table1
WHERE column3 IN
(
    SELECT TOP(1) column4
    FROM table2
    INNER JOIN table3
    ON table2.column1 = table3.column1
)
"""
```

For syntax highlight, however, since PyCharm is build for Python specifically, I don't think you can change the settings to highlight like in SQL. There may be extensions for this, however, I do not know of any.

Comment: Thank you, I searched a lot meanwhile, and found only for Professional version there is plugin: Database Tools and SQL https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/relational-databases.html - which seems crazy overkill for just highlighting syntax.

Answer (score 1):

using `""" """`

```
sql = """
        SELECT column1
     , column2
FROM table1
WHERE column3 IN
(
    SELECT TOP(1) column4
    FROM table2
    INNER JOIN table3
    ON table2.column1 = table3.column1
)
"""

print(sql)
```