# How to enable autocomplete for Django HTML files in Pycharm?

Tags: html, django, pycharm, autoformatting

How to get my Django HTML files color coded correctly? Currently none of the variables or tags are recognized by Pycharm. However, within the same file the basic html syntax is recognized (autocomplete and color coded):

[snippet of Pycharm code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzm1B.png)

I have tried to add Django in:

1. Setting > Color Scheme
2. Settings > Languages & Frameworks

But it does not seem to show as an option.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Autocomplete and syntax highlight are separate functionalities, here's an example of using [language injection for SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66557321) the same applies to HTML just choose that as a language.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Language & Framewroks -> Django

- Enable Django supprot
- Add project root (your folder), settings (path to settings.py), manage scripts (path to manage.py), folder pattern to track files (type `migrations`)
- Apply and restart

OR

Editor -> Live templates

- Check `Django`
- apply and restart